# how to create android project with gradle build tool in eclipse from terminal?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

Just like maven :--

```
    mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-release \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.11 \
    -DgroupId=com.foo.bar \
    -DartifactId=my-android-project \
   -Dpackage=com.foo.bar.android \
```

this the command for creating android project with maven build tool..
I used   `http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes`..
There are another build tool gradle..how can I create android project with gradle like the maven??I have search in google but nowhere I find the proper description..How to create android project with gradle in eclipse and run commands from terminal..